# Rotate 3D with CSS in JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx, rotation

In Text Node,

We can apply

```
Rotate rotate = new Rotate(-30, Rotate.Y_AXIS);
```

By Java code,
But we need to apply them by CSS,
How can we do that?

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't use the tag "java-3d" for questions that aren't related to the Java3D API as you use the JavaFX 3D API which isn't the same API.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I will follow this next time

Answer (score 1):

There is no css property to rotate on the Y or Z axis. So you need to use code or write your own node class that has custom css properties for that.

Comment: This is why my order, I can not control by code, I can only in css, this is sad, thank you for spending your time in answering

Comment: When you have control over the fxml (if there is any), its maybe possible to set it over the fxml with the <fx:define> tag.

Comment: or even <Label><transforms><Rotate .../></transforms></Label> should work. :P

Answer (score 0):

```
`-fx-rotate: -30`
```

will do the Job

Refer below example,

```
public class Main extends Application {

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Label label1 = new Label("Rotate");
    label1.setStyle("-fx-rotate: -30");
    VBox vBox = new VBox(label1);
    vBox.setPadding(new Insets(10.0));
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(vBox, 100, 100));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }
}
```

Output will be like this ,

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this is not 3D